# Sum Of Digits BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I was trying to find the sum of digits of a BigInteger and found this code.

```
BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(1000);
String digits = big.toString();
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
    int digit = (int) (digits.charAt(i) - '0');
    sum = sum + digit;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

I don't understand why  `- '0'` is added in 6th line of the code.

```
int digit = (int) (digits.charAt(i) - '0');
```

If I remove that part it gives me a wrong answer.

For example sum of digits of 16 without `- '0'` gives 103 as the answer instead of 7.

So, can anyone explain the importance of that part in the code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks! I understood it :)

Comment: It’s an aside, the code is low-level. Better to use `Character.getNumericValue()` to convert the char '6' to the int 6.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, got it. Btw what do you mean by "It's an aside"?

Comment: I just meant, your question was about that specific code and my comment was not, so it was not contributing to answering the specific question. Thought it could be useful for some anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `digits.charAt(i)` gives you the ASCII code for the digit. So if you look at an [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), you'll see the value of the character `7` is 55 and the value of character `0` is 48. If you subtract `0` from `7`, you'll get 7, which is the digit you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: I have second method too using string.split()  for(String rr:n.split(""))
            {
                s=s.add(new BigInteger(rr));
            }

Answer (score 1):

For example if you take a `'5'` from `digits.getCharAt(i)`:

```
'5' - '0' = ?
```

According to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) Can be translated to:

```
53 - 48
```

Which is 5 and it's the result you're looking for

Comment: '5' is not casted to 5! As you mentioned correctly the char '5' has the asciicode 53 and '0' has 48. You simply calculate the difference of the two asciicodes... Yes the result on calculating is the same when using asciicodes of digits, but not due to casting

Comment: @Karl fixed, I let myself go with the casting part on OP's code. You were right